# I have a script to append values into a 2 tables.While executing the script it is showing error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

> Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Procedure Trig_InsertToInvoiceDetails,
>   Line 45 Cannot insert duplicate key row in object
>   'dbo.TT_InvoiceDetails' with unique index 'idx_Invdtl'. The duplicate
>   key value is (152245, 2018/03/IC17-334, 135). The statement has been
>   terminated.

But what ever i am passing those are unique values only

Comment: Show us yor code, please!

Comment: what is the script are you talking about? please atleast share your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 cases

1. Against unique index 'idx_Invdtl'there is chances already row saved with values 152245, 2018/03/IC17-334, 135)
2. Secondly, your saving process works not well it is passing same values for saving.

Comment: So, check your table data and one thing more has you table any trigger?

Comment: ya trigger is there

Comment: Please check the trigger. what is doing in it? or share here.

Comment: The error message is very clear, you are inserting the same values twice and it even shows you which values. SInce database errors do not lie you need to examen if the values are not already in there, or if your code inserts it twice, or if it is 2 times in your input. Since you dont share your code we cannot help you with that

Comment: There is a third case possible, the input he uses could hold the same value 2 times. His saving process should check that so it could handled in your second case, but I mention it anyway because maybe he forgot this extra check